# Changing image properties UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = nil
    let imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "first")

    // cell.imageView?.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
    // or
    // cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)

    // also tried this


    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "first")  
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

Neither seems to make a difference.

When the image loads from the URL online it takes its original size.

I have omitted the code used for asynchronous image downloading because I figure its the same problem here. If not let me know. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you should explain in little more detail what are u trying to do, maybe some screenshots or prototiping would be nice. I'm failing on imaginate why are you trying to change width, height, x and y ..(alpha is an easy one)

Answer (score 1):

You should set `Mode` property of your `UIImageView` into **Aspect Fit** where you are showing the image at your cell.

Comment: I tried `cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill` ... nothing unfortunately

Comment: I would also like to set specific width, height, x, y and alpha value. Is this possible?

Comment: please, read again @GregoryPeck, I wrote **Fit** and not **Fill** the results are different

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `contentmode` of the `imageView` either in code or in Interface Builder, and then once you do that you need to use`cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Could you show an example... I tried `cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill` and it did nothing
`

Comment: Did you set the `clipstoBounds` property? You might also need to `import QuartzCore`

Comment: I would also like to set specific width, height, x, y and alpha value. Is this possible?